# Why does Mypy return error when I call a fronzen dataclass property as a function?

Tags: python, mypy

OkCase1, OkCase2, and var are no problem.
But Mypy returned this message for `self.func(input)` in MypyErrorCase1

`Invalid self argument "MypyErrorCase1" to attribute function "func" with type "Callable[[Input], Result]"`
`"Result" not callable`

The error is Mypy bug? (Should I create an issue on Mypy?)
Or Should Mypy return an error for the calling frozen dataclass attribute as a function?

(In any case, the 2nd error message `"Result" not callable` is not suitable.)

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Callable


class Input:
    pass


class Result:
    pass


FuncA = Callable[[Input], Result]


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class OkCase1:
    func: FuncA

    def call_func(self):
        return self.func()


@dataclass
class OkCase2:
    func: FuncA

    def call_func(self, input: Input):
        return self.func(input)


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class MypyErrorCase1:
    func: FuncA

    def call_func(self, input: Input):
        return self.func(input)


var: FuncA = lambda input: Result()  # No Error

# [{
#   "resource": "/Users/me/mypy_said_not_callable.py",
#   "owner": "python",
#   "code": "error",
#   "severity": 8,
#   "message": "Invalid self argument \"MypyErrorCase1\" to attribute function \"func\" with type \"Callable[[Input], Result]\"",
#   "source": "mypy",
#   "startLineNumber": 37,
#   "startColumn": 16,
#   "endLineNumber": 37,
#   "endColumn": 16
# }]

# [{
#   "resource": "/Users/me/mypy_said_not_callable.py",
#   "owner": "python",
#   "code": "error",
#   "severity": 8,
#   "message": "\"Result\" not callable",
#   "source": "mypy",
#   "startLineNumber": 37,
#   "startColumn": 16,
#   "endLineNumber": 37,
#   "endColumn": 16
# }]
```

```
$ python --version
Python 3.9.7

$ mypy --version
mypy 0.910

$ mypy example.py
example.py:37: error: Invalid self argument "MypyErrorCase1" to attribute function "func" with type "Callable[[Input], Result]"
example.py:37: error: "Result" not callable
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Comment: I am wondering why `OkCase1` is ok. Aren't you missing the `Input`-argument in `self.func(...)` there? Btw., you import `List` for no use.

Comment: @matheburg Yes. I didn't pass `Input` to self.func in OkCase1, But Mypy didn't output an error for OkCase1.

Comment: `List` is not used as you said. I removed `List`.

Comment: This looks like a myy bug. Mypy probably thinks that `self.func` constructs a bound method with `self` as the first argument to the function.

Comment: The bug is already known: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6910